# Occurence of support

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing Facebook login Application. There I can't initiate the activity subclass `FragmentActivity` instead of Activity. Please find below the code I've used.

Error: Occurence of support in line import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

```
package com.example.testfb;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.example.testfb.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private MainFragment mainfragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if(savedInstanceState==null)
            {
                //add the fragement on initial actiovity setup
                mainfragment=new MainFragment();


            }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

              //Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have the support library in libs folder

Comment: add `v4-support library` to your project build path

Comment: @Gopal Rao how can i add it.please help me

Comment: @RehanK is support library downloaded in the first place from the sdk manager

Comment: @GopalRao i have installed Android support Library 19.0.1 but this version i could imported it i think thats the problem i got

Comment: @RehanK I think you should consider nonanhex answer...

Comment: @RehanK make sure its in your project library folder if not right click project -> Android Tools -> Add support Library; there is also typo in the import for support library as mention by nonahex.

Comment: goto `android-sdks/extras/android/support/v4` folder in your android-sdk, copy `android-support-v4.jar` file, paste it in `libs` folder of your project. after pasting, right click on that jar file and click `add to BuildPath`...

Comment: @GopalRao in my libs i found android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that your build path not recognize the android -support-V4.jar .then you have to go and Error and find the highlighted window there you can find project fix solution below that you will find the adding Build path into your app and support-V4.jar. and click it then you're problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in your import. You have

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragementActivity;
```

but it should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Comment: @nonahex import android.support  cannot be resloved

Comment: @nonahex now im getting Error Occurence of support

Answer (score 0):

checkout your sdk version in manifest...

Comment: <uses-sdk minimumVersion="11" targetsdkversion="16"/>